# risk prediction

Tags: regression, logistic, validation

i am doing cardiovascular risk estimation for my undergradute research, so i get 12 risk factors as a independent variables and risk value is my dependent value.in this situation , why i need to clasify into traning and testing cohorts as i seen in many research articles?
can i use logistic regression analysis for my research to predict a risk estimation value like percentage?
what are the steps i have to follow?
if u please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Is prediction the only task of your model? Thus, no hypothesis testing or effect estimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question. When the risk you are trying to predict has two outcomes - hart infarct occurs or not - then a technique like logistic regression is fine. More advanced prediction models are also available. When all your input variables come from continuous distributions you can compare the outcomes of your logistic classifier with that of linear and quadratic discriminant analysis.

You need to choose a certain ***time window*** within which the hart infarct occurs. When occurring later than that then it should not count.

The random separation into training and test sets is necessary to assess possible overfitting in your predictive models. Use your test set for that at the final stage.

Comment: thank you so much for your opinion.highly appriciate !